# When and where were the mother and father of Buddha born?

Tags: the-buddha

Undoubtedly Buddha was a very famous person. I am very eager to know who were his mother and father and when and where they were born?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quote from Wikipedia's [Family of Gautama Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_Gautama_Buddha):

> The Buddha was born into a family of the kshatriya varna in what is Nepal in 567BCE. He was called Siddhartha in his childhood. His father was King Suddhodana, leader of the Shakya clan in what was the growing state of Kosala, and his mother was Queen Maya. He was raised by his mother's younger sister Maha Pajapati after his mother's death seven days after childbirth.
>
> He later married Yaśodharā, and together they had one child, a son, Rāhula. Both Yaśodharā and Rāhula later became disciples of Buddha.
>
> His first cousin, by his father, Ananda, joined the Buddha as his attendant.

I would also recommend 2 books for you. The first one is called ["What Buddhists Believe"](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/whatbelieve.pdf) by Ven. K. Sri Dhammanda and ["The Buddha and His Teachings"](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/buddha-teachingsurw6.pdf) by Ven. Narada Mahathera.

Both books have an introductory section on the life of the Buddha. In the second book there are also 2 chapters on the Buddha's relatives.